# *** extconf.rb failed *** error when install muby mud client

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I am not that experienced with ubuntu - I'm on Ubuntu 13.04 and am trying to install muby (http://rubyforge.org/projects/muby/).
When I downloaded it and tried to gem install... this is the error I get:

[image]

If someone could please tell me how to fix this - I have searched google extensively and installed many things (like mysql, ruby versions and -dev's... Haven't tried RVM because I don't know how).

**Update** After having installed `libncurses5-dev`, I get this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing muby-0.7.19.gem:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ncurses.h... yes
checking for wmove() in -lncurses... yes
checking for newscr()... yes
checking for TABSIZE()... yes
checking for ESCDELAY()... yes
checking for keybound()... yes
checking for curses_version()... yes
checking for tigetstr()... yes
checking for getwin()... yes
checking for putwin()... yes
checking for ungetmouse()... yes
checking for mousemask()... yes
checking for wenclose()... yes
checking for mouseinterval()... yes
checking for wmouse_trafo()... yes
checking for mcprint()... yes
checking for has_key()... yes
checking for delscreen()... yes
checking for define_key()... yes
checking for keyok()... yes
checking for resizeterm()... yes
checking for use_default_colors()... yes
checking for use_extended_names()... yes
checking for wresize()... yes
checking for attr_on()... yes
checking for attr_off()... yes
checking for attr_set()... yes
checking for chgat()... yes
checking for color_set()... yes
checking for filter()... yes
checking for intrflush()... yes
checking for mvchgat()... yes
checking for mvhline()... yes
checking for mvvline()... yes
checking for mvwchgat()... yes
checking for mvwhline()... yes
checking for mvwvline()... yes
checking for noqiflush()... yes
checking for putp()... yes
checking for qiflush()... yes
checking for scr_dump()... yes
checking for scr_init()... yes
checking for scr_restore()... yes
checking for scr_set()... yes
checking for slk_attr_off()... no
checking for slk_attr_on()... no
checking for slk_attr()... yes
checking for slk_attr_set()... yes
checking for slk_color()... yes
checking for tigetflag()... yes
checking for tigetnum()... yes
checking for use_env()... yes
checking for vidattr()... yes
checking for vid_attr()... no
checking for wattr_on()... yes
checking for wattr_off()... yes
checking for wattr_set()... yes
checking for wchgat()... yes
checking for wcolor_set()... yes
checking for getattrs()... yes
checking which debugging functions to wrap...
checking for _tracef()... no
checking for _tracedump()... no
checking for _nc_tracebits()... no
checking for _traceattr()... no
checking for _traceattr2()... no
checking for _tracechar()... no
checking for _tracechtype()... no
checking for _tracechtype2()... no
checking for _tracemouse()... no
checking for other functions that appeared after ncurses version 5.0...
checking for assume_default_colors()... yes
checking for attr_get()... yes
checking for the panel library...
checking for panel.h... yes
checking for panel_hidden() in -lpanel... yes
checking for the form library...
checking for form.h... yes
checking for new_form() in -lform... yes
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:176: warning: overriding commands for target `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ncurses-0.9.1/lib'
Makefile:174: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ncurses-0.9.1/lib'
compiling form_wrap.c
form_wrap.c: In function ‘rbncurs_m_new_form’:
form_wrap.c:395:34: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
form_wrap.c: In function ‘rbncurs_c_set_field_type’:
form_wrap.c:619:23: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
form_wrap.c:624:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘STR2CSTR’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
form_wrap.c:624:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
form_wrap.c: In function ‘rbncurs_c_set_field_buffer’:
form_wrap.c:741:3: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘set_field_buffer’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from form_wrap.h:26:0,
                 from form_wrap.c:28:
/usr/include/form.h:341:28: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
form_wrap.c: In function ‘rbncurs_c_set_form_fields’:
form_wrap.c:778:34: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
form_wrap.c: In function ‘rbncurs_c_form_request_by_name’:
form_wrap.c:1051:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘form_request_by_name’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from form_wrap.h:26:0,
                 from form_wrap.c:28:
/usr/include/form.h:403:28: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
form_wrap.c: In function ‘make_arg’:
form_wrap.c:1126:38: error: ‘struct RArray’ has no member named ‘len’
form_wrap.c:1130:5: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [form_wrap.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ncurses-0.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ncurses-0.9.1/./gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:

```
checking for ncurses.h... no
...
...
...: ncurses hearder file not found
```

You just have to install the ncurses development package:

```
apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

**Update** That's a bug in the `ncurses` gem that is not updated to work with Ruby 1.9+, switch to Ruby 1.8.7, if you can, and it will build with no errors. Unfortunately this gem seems to be no longer manteainded.

You can quite easily install Ruby 1.8.7 using [rvm](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#table-of-contents), I suggest the latter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! However, I installed that and though it did get much further, I still got this error:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6SUVrVbt

Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, I purged ruby1.9.1 and ruby1.8 and then reinstalled ruby 1.8.7.358-7ubuntu1... I then tried again and got: bash: /usr/bin/gem: No such file or directory
I apologise for not know anything about this...!
I have these packages installed:
libncurses-ruby* libruby1.8* ruby-ncurses* ruby1.8* ruby1.8-dev*

Comment: You are missing the `rubygems` package, it is not included with Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. This is what I got: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YHSiC98Y - But now that it is installed.. I still can't find it in my applications. Am I supposed to do something else to install this program? Or should it be there?